# My image gallery (slider) stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I am using the Florance theme and it comes with a sliding image gallery using jquery and jcarousellite. Somehow it stopped working (it was ok 2 days) and error (object does not support this property or method) points to the script. The site in question is [www.happystay.net](http://www.happystay.net)

Please, i need some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you think of any changes you've made to the site in that time span? Anything at all, however minor?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you're using jQuery.noConflict() right before you declare the Carousel. Is there anything in particular on the page that you're trying to avoid conflict with?

I used Safari's javascript console to run the carousel without the jQuery.noConflict() part, and it seemed to kick into gear. Try editting the script to run using the plain old jQuery $ sign and see what happens.

Edit: Here is what the code might look like if you were to remove the noConflict.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mygallery").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".nextb",
    btnPrev: ".prevb",
    visible: 1,
    easing: "backout",
    auto: 800,
    speed: 1500
  });
});
</script>
```

Generally speaking there is no reason to use noConflict unless another script is competing for the $ variable. A common example is if you are trying to use jQuery and MooTools on the same website.

Comment: thanks. Do you mean remove 

var $jx = jQuery.noConflict(); 
$jx(function() { $jx(".mygallery").jCarouselLite({ 

and replace with 

$(document).ready(function(){ 

$jx(".mygallery").jCarouselLite({ 


Sorry. I am a novice in javascript. if you can elaborate further, it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

please do this....
after line that has this `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.happystay.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>`

put 
`<script type="text/javascript"> var $jx = jQuery.noConflict(); </script>`

it should now look like this... on line 17

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.happystay.net/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $jx = jQuery.noConflict(); // note i added this line</script>  
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.happystay.net/wp-content/themes/Florance/js/jquery.easing.1.1.js?ver=2.9.2'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.happystay.net/wp-content/themes/Florance/js/jcarousel.js?ver=2.9.2'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.happystay.net/wp-content/themes/Florance/js/jquery.mousewheel.js?ver=2.9.2'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.happystay.net/wp-content/themes/Florance/js/cufon.js?ver=2.9.2'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.happystay.net/wp-content/themes/Florance/js/Liberation_Serif_400.font.js?ver=2.9.2'></script>
```

then line 246 should now be this...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$jx(document).ready(function(){
$jx(".mygallery").jCarouselLite({
btnNext: ".nextb",
        btnPrev: ".prevb",
      visible: 1,
      easing: "backout",
      auto: 800,
       speed: 1500
    });

});
</script>
```

Hope it fixes it....
demo [here](http://jsbin.com/ilogo3)
explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833883/weird-chrome-prototype-jquery-conflict)

**edit:**

ok, so it's a wordpress...
hmmmm how about in the php script add

`echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var $jx = jQuery.noConflict();</script>";`

**after**

`wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`

Comment: Thanks. that sits under a php script wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); wp_enqueue_script('easing', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.easing.1.1.js'); 


What is the exact script that I need to input to make it work?

Comment: well, I'm not a guru on wordpress but your codes (when in html already) should be like the demo above...