# jQuery / Prototype conflict: only in webkit, in bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, bookmarklet, conflict

I most likely have the same problem as in this question:

[Weird Chrome prototype/jQuery conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833883/weird-chrome-prototype-jquery-conflict)

Basically it appears Prototype is conflicting with jQuery in Safari and Chrome. The solution in the question was to include prototype first, however I can't do that:  I'm using jQuery loaded in my bookmarklet, and so some sites it is used on will always have Prototype already loaded.  Now let's ignore for the moment the wisdom of using jQuery in the bookmarklet.  It seems to me there should be a solution here (though I can't find it), for these reasons:

1) This conflict does not appear to occur at all in Firefox. 
2) Though the question linked to above cites a page stipulating that jQuery should be included first,  I no longer find that reference there.  So maybe it is not current?

Error Example: once jQuery is loaded (e.g. you can test it's version -1.4.4),  if you try in the firebug console:

```
jQuery('p:') 
#yields =>  []
#or    
jQuery('p:first')
# yields => TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'find'
```

Some other notes: 
-I have tried noConflict().  This does not seem to work at all.
-I never refer to '$' in my code, but only use 'jQuery'
-Using jQuery from the Google CDN
-Moving all the bookmarklet code into a frame would be very difficult, if possible at all, so I'd rather not go there.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any chance you could show the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is now fixed in jquery 1.5+ ....

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this for a client project, and ran into the exact same issue. After some research it looks like the conflict doesn't exist in 1.4.2, but does in 1.4.3 (I'm not sure about later versions). I downgraded to 1.4.2 and my bookmarklet now works on pages with Prototype.

Third comment here:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-conflicts-with-prototype-and-the-fix