# Javascript: Seemingly valid code causing Uncaught Error: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9 on line 3

Tags: javascript

```
var returned = values.make(function (value, index) {
    return items[index].value = value;
});
```

I have the above snippet.

Values is an array of values to be assigned to different elements.

Make is essentially the equivalent of Array.prototype.map.

```
Array.prototype.make = function (loop, playground) {
    var loop = loop || function (value) { return value },
        playground = playground || this;

    if (loop.Type !== "Function") throw "Loop [0] is not a function.";

    var returned = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        returned[i] = loop.apply(playground, [this[i], i, this]);

    return returned;
};
```

Also, I have `Function.prototype.Type = "Function";` in the same file, so **it's not `.Type` throwing an error. `.Type` works perfectly.**

Along with Function, these also have `.Type`'s.

```
Object.prototype.Type = "Object";
Array.prototype.Type = "Array";
RegExp.prototype.Type = "RegExp";
String.prototype.Type = "String";
Number.prototype.Type = "Number";
Boolean.prototype.Type = "Boolean";
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.Type = "XMLHttpRequest";
Date.prototype.Type = "Date";
```

Items is the array of different elements.

```
[<input type="text" />, <input type="text" />, <input type="text" />]
```

I keep getting this error.

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9 on line 3
```

I get that error and it doesn't make any sense, because there isn't any code on that line.

I'm at a total loss.

Does anyone notice anything wrong with that code?

**Update:** I don't know what happened, but I fixed it.

Since no one gave the correct answer, I'll just give it to the only guy who tried.

*clap clap clap*

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833883/weird-chrome-prototype-jquery-conflict) deals with the same error message. You might find some useful information there.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example that produces the same error? Also, the source for `make()` would help.

Comment: Can you post rest of the code? Specially make

Comment: @Tesserex It says in the question. Right about the error message. It's a bunch of input elements on an page.

Comment: The error is probably coming from `make()`, can you include that code and also the `items` array?

Comment: Ah sorry. Yeah, it would still be nice to have the code for make as well.

Comment: @Vivin @Cybernate @mVChr @Tesserex Tada.

Comment: @tylermwashburn Tada! Heh, Uhh can you also update with a call to make? 99% sure it's the function, curious how you trigger it.

Comment: @Khez What do you mean? It's in the first block of code. Right at the top. Very first line of the entire question.

Comment: Can I ask what `.Type` is and why `Function` is capitalized? Is there a reason it's not `typeof loop !== 'function'`?

Comment: @Eli Updated answer. Check it out.

Comment: But if you have Type `defined` on `Function`, it would be undefined on other objects. It's just an opinion, but I don't think you are gaining anything from doing this. You could have easily said `Function.prototype.isFunction = true;` and use it like so: `if (loop.isFunction)`. Still wouldn't recommend it, but a little simpler I suppose...

Comment: I also have `Object.prototype.Type = "Object"` so that **EVERYTHING** has a `.Type` to fall back on, if there isn't a specific name supplied.

Comment: @Vivin It says you edited it, but I don't see what. xD

Comment: @tylermwashburn Extending native prototypes. You are the _devil_.

Comment: @Raynos The first JavaScript I ever wrote used [MooTools](http://mootools.net). It's in my blood.

Comment: @tylermwashburn Using MooTools instead of jQuery. You are the _devil_.

Comment: @Raynos Because jQuery is almost twice the size of MooTools, and no where near as good.

Comment: @tylermwashburn That second one was a joke. MooTools is fine. Extending native prototypes is still evil.

Comment: @Raynos That's pretty much all MooTools does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you post a small example that reproduces this error?

Other than that, there are a few errors in your Javascript:

I added a semicolon here:

```
var loop = loop || function (value) { return value; },
   playground = playground || this;
```

Although semicolons are not necessary, I like to use them because otherwise you can be bitten by subtle errors.

<s>And, you need to use `typeof` not `.Type`:</s>

```
if (typeof loop !== "function") throw "Loop [0] is not a function.";
```

Also, if `items` is just an array of strings as you have, then `items[index].value` doesn't make sense, since strings don't have a `value` property. This part looks particularly suspicious to me. Although I didn't get the same error you did when I left that bit in, I think it would merit closer examination.

You mentioned that you're using a 3rd-party library so the part about `typeof` doesn't matter. You also mentioned that you were using actual `input` elements in your array so the second part doesn't matter either.

I tried out your code again, this time creating `input` elements with `document.createElement`:

```
Array.prototype.make = function (loop, playground) {
    var loop = loop || function (value) { return value; },
        playground = playground || this;

    if (typeof loop !== "function") throw "Loop [0] is not a function.";

    var returned = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        returned[i] = loop.apply(playground, [this[i], i, this]);

    return returned;
};

var items = [];
items.push(document.createElement("INPUT"));
items.push(document.createElement("INPUT"));
items.push(document.createElement("INPUT"));

var values = [4, 5, 6];

var returned = values.make(function (value, index) {
    return items[index].value = value;
});

console.log(items[0].value, items[1].value, items[2].value);

//firebug shows: 4 5 6
```

So it appears that your code is working by itself. Can you try this code out by itself on a fresh page? That way you can verify if it is something on the original page that is interacting with your code and causing this error.

Comment: @cwolves Technically, no. But not using semicolons consistently can lead to subtle problems.

Comment: +1 I think this is the key: "Also, if `items` is just an array of strings as you have, then `items[index].value` doesn't make sense, since strings don't have a `value` property."

Comment: @Vivin They aren't strings. They **are** elements. I typed that line by hand and it's habit of mine to use quotes, because I wasn't typing a variable name, function, object, number etc.

Comment: @Vivin And I use a toolkit I made called Ally, that defines .Type for array's, function's, object's etc. It supplies more detail then `typeof` so I prefer to use it.

Comment: @Vivin There's no technicality about it. It's not an error. I do agree that you should use it, jsLint and jsMinifiers use `;` to properly work.

Comment: @tylermwashburn I don't understand. What do you mean by "They are elements"? Do you mean that you got them from `document.getElementById()`? Also I didn't know that you were using a 3rd-party library. So disregard my point about that. Might want to add that information to your question though :)

Comment: @Vivin `document.querySelectorAll('div#id > input')`

Comment: @Khez I don't understand what you mean by there is no technicality :) Technically, semicolons are not required :) It's automatic semicolon-insertion that *can* cause problems. You can write semicolon-less Javascript as long as you are well-versed with the semicolon-insertion rules. :)

Comment: @Vivin About the semicolon: I write a lot of little single line functions like that. When there are 2 or more lines of code, I'm anal about using semicolons, but when it's just 1, I prefer to leave them out.

Comment: Added a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/bLuyQ/) just for testing sake's. P.S. Your prototype.Type will deal a massive blow to resources on the client machine.

Comment: @Khez thanks for the fiddle - I really need to get on using that :p it always slips my mind :)

Comment: @Vivin I'm really curious where the error is being triggered.

Comment: @Khez me too. I think it something else on the page that is triggering it, since by itself the code runs fine.

Comment: @Vivin I found out what it was, but it's far to detailed for me to care to explain it all to you. Just know that you get points for being the only one to really try. xD

Comment: @tylermwashburn ok :) but if you think the actual solution might be helpful for others, you should post it :)

Comment: @Vivin I was trying to modify a constant. `0++` throws an error. `0+1` and `var i=0; i++` both work though. I don't think that will really matter to anyone else.

Comment: @Vivin But I don't get why it chose to say that that line was throwing the error. It should've either been a line about 4 lines earlier, or line 2.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue in a different scenario, but using the latest version of Prototype (1.7 instead of 1.5) fixed it.