# Javascripts conflict in Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, conflict

my website name is marutiindia.in. I am using two extensions -- module and plugin. Module uses mootools(I think it is mootools---script_12.js) and the other employs jQuery. The module is on homepage. When I try to enable these both extensions I get this error in script_12.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getElement'
```

but the the plugin works fine and when I disable this plugin there is no error. So I guess this is some conflict between mootools and jQuery. So I made use of this script for the plugin jQuery file:

```
if(jQuery){ 
  jQuery.noConflict(); 
}
```

But this doesn't resolve the error.
Am I doing it right or is there something else I am missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you already have JQuery running. (K2 uses it, which may be the issue.) It is likely an script ordering issue like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833883/weird-chrome-prototype-jquery-conflict). Also, do JQuery no conflict more like [this](http://www.minitek.gr/tutorials/javascript-tutorials/item/99-how-to-use-the-jquery-no-conflict-mode.html)

Comment: Thanks. I got it resolved. It was conflict between two different versions of jquery.

Answer (score 2):

only doing this

```
if(jQuery){ 
  jQuery.noConflict(); 
}
```

does not resolve your problem, if in the jquery module you have `$` sign then the same conflict problem you will face.

To rid from this conflict try with this:

```
jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery(function(){
    //replace all the '$' with 'jQuery'
    jQuery('#some_id').show();
    //instead of
    //$('#some_id').show();
});
```