# jquery conflict with my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I layout'd a page and on my server which is it hostgator works extremely fine, using the jQuery mobile components:

http://brunolustro.com/roger/teste/cadastro.html

But my friend who is programming the page wanted me to insert the newest CDNs from either jQuery and jQuery Mobile:

And this is what the page looks like when I insert those codes:

http://brunolustro.com/roger/test/cadastro.html

Do you know how to fix this?

Regards,
Bruno

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird Chrome prototype/jQuery conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833883/weird-chrome-prototype-jquery-conflict)

Comment: If you open your console, you will notice that jQuery is not found on the second page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with JavaScript or jQuery on your website - if something isn't working as you intend - the first thing you should do is check the browser console to see if anything is being logged there.

To check the browser console:

Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> on your keyboard. When the developer tools open, choose the console tab, its placed in the toolbar at the top of the new window.

In the console you will see a few errors in red with error codes (404). A 404 means the requested file wasn't found.

This tells us that your reference to jQuery isn't correct. This could be because the file path you've written isn't correct, or that you haven't deployed those files correctly to your site.

Check your file paths you've referenced and make sure the file is on your server. Once both are correct - the errors should go away.

Here's a link to view more about developer tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#console

Answer (score 0):

Check following files in your "test/js" and "teste/js" folders, because i've got 404 not found error:

1. jquery-2.0.3.min.js
2. modernizr-2.6.2.min.js
3. jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.map